# Proper plugin architecture for Express (Node.js)

Tags: node.js

We have been asked by an industry association to create an online software platform for their members. Roughly 70% of the functionality will be standard stuff like customers, products, orders, payments, distributors, etc. The other 30% will be very specific to that individual member. Things like distributor compensation schemes, product specials, distributor incentives. And some of this 30% can be quite complicated and very unique (and proprietary) to the individual member.

We feel the best approach is to allow for plugins for the unique 30%, so that each member will have their own plugins on-top of the 70% base. We will, of course, need a published API for the plugins to interact with.

We lack experience in this area, and would like to hear from the community as to the proper architecture for this platform, especially considering all the newer technologies coming out. Buzzwords around the office include docker containers, SOA, etc.

Our stack is linux, node.js, [express](http://expressjs.com/), [jade](http://jade-lang.com/), and Firebird DBMS.